# How do I transfer the string value from a label to another label whenever a button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I've tried innerText instead of value but the code still doesn't work properly.

I'm new to javascript and other code examples of it being done didn't help me figure out
why it wasn't working.

//my html

```
<div class="display">
  <h1>Enter Your name</h1>
  <label for="textbox_name">Enter Name</label>
  <input type="texbox_name" class="textbox_id" placeholder="Enter Name" />
  <button class="submit">Submit</button>`enter code here`
  <input class="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
</div>
```

//my javascript

```
var theName = document.querySelector(".textbox_id").value;
var submit = document.querySelector(".submit");
var input = document.querySelector(".name");

submit.addEventListener("click", () => {
theName = input.value;
});
```

thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

```
var theName = document.querySelector(".textbox_id").value;
```

Here you've made a copy of the element's value. So later when you write:

```
theName = input.value;
```

...you are changing the value of the *copy*, not the original element. Instead try `theName = document.querySelector(".textbox_id)";` and `theName.value = input.value;`

Comment: oh that was so helpful holy cow. It works now